# Not able to redeploy the app after upgrading the heroku stack

Tags: heroku

We are in process of upgrading the heroku stack from 18 to 22. After clicking on upgrade while we are trying to redeploy the app we are getting the below error while doing git push:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test.git'
```

We are following the below steps to redeploy:

$ heroku git:clone -a test

$ cd test

$ git add .

$ git commit -am "make it better"

$ git push heroku master

Also we have followed the below steps from CLI as well

To upgrade via the Heroku CLI, use the stack:set command on your production app:

heroku stack:set heroku-22 -a test
Setting stack to heroku-22... done
You will need to redeploy ⬢ for the change to take effect.
Run git push heroku main to trigger a new build on ⬢ .

git commit --allow-empty -m "Upgrading to heroku-22"

```
[master (root-commit) 89fea09] Upgrading to heroku-22
```

git push heroku master

```
Enumerating objects: 2, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 185 bytes | 185.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: error: pathspec '.' did not match any file(s) known to git.
remote:
remote: ! Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.
remote: ! See http://status.heroku.com for current Heroku platform status.
remote: ! If the problem persists, please open a ticket
remote: ! on https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new

remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/test.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test.git'
bhattacharjee.c@bhattac-ltmynzq ei-mule-dashboard-ee1 % git push heroku main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test.git'.
```

We are getting the below error here:

```
remote: error: pathspec '.' did not match any file(s) known to git.
remote:
remote: ! Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.
remote: ! See http://status.heroku.com for current Heroku platform status.
remote: ! If the problem persists, please open a ticket
remote: ! on https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new
```

remote:

```
To https://git.heroku.com/test.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test.git'
bhattacharjee.c@bhattac-ltmynzq ei-mule-dashboard-ee1 % git push heroku main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test.git'.
```

Could you please help us in resloving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> We are following the below steps to redeploy:
>
> ```
> $ heroku git:clone -a test
> ```

First of all, [you shouldn't be doing this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub.

If this is part of your regular workflow, please adjust accordingly. Heroku is not a source code management platform.

Now, onto the problem:

```
src refspec master does not match any
```

You simply don't have a `master` branch.

[Heroku builds from one of two branches](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploy-your-code): `main` (which is newer and slowly becoming the community standard default branch name) and `master` (legacy).

If you don't have a `master` branch, you almost certainly have a `main` branch that Heroku will happy build from:

```
git push heroku main
```

If you need to deploy from some other branch `another-branch`, you still need to push to `main` (or `master`) on Heroku:

```
git push heroku another-branch:main
```

Finally, please don't actually use "make it better" as a commit message. Spend some time making commit messages clear and meaningful. There is lots of [good advice](https://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html) floating around about how you can do that.

Comment: Hi Chris, If i use git push heroku main then I am getting the errorerror: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ei-mule-dashboard-e2e.git'

Comment: @Chandradeep, did your `heroku git:clone` command generate a repository with any commits in it? How did you deploy in the past? Via `git push`, GitHub integration, Docker, "Deploy to Heroku" button, ...?

Comment: while using master we are getting the below error:     
remote: error: pathspec '.' did not match any file(s) known to git.
remote:
remote: ! Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/test.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test.git'

Comment: git clone is creating empty repo. When I am using slug I am able to see the apps getting downloaded.

Comment: Again, how did you deploy before? I suspect it wasn't via `git push`.

Comment: Is there any way we can check how it was deployed before

Comment: @Chandradeep, why don't you know? You might be able to tell by looking at your deploy log in the dashboard. In any case, `git push` is the only deployment method that populates Heroku's underlying Git repository. You can't use `heroku git:clone` to get source code that wasn't `git push`ed to Heroku. As I said in my answer, that should not be part of your regular workflow. Do you have a copy of the source code somewhere, e.g. on a development machine or on GitHub?

Comment: @Chandradeep, have you figured out how you were deploying before? Have you tracked down a copy of the application's source code?